# Error de llave en redirect->route de laravel funcion "Store"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, routes

si me hace el insert pero no me redirecciona a la vista porque me da un error en la llave de cierre de la función, el error me  lo empieza a marcar desde inventario2 en adelante, al quitar esas lineas todo funciona bien y la llave del final ya no marca error

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{

    $orden = new ordenDS;
    $orden->folio = $request->input('folio');
    $orden->serie = $request->input('serie');
    $orden->folioSerie = $request->input('serie').$request->input('folio');
    $orden->cliente_id = $request->input('livesearch');
    $orden->contacto_id = $request->input('livesearchContact');
    $orden->save();

    $var = $orden->id;

    $inventario = new inventario;
    $inventario->fecha = $request->input('fecha');
    $inventario->numSerie = $request->input('numeroSerie');
    $inventario->descripcionOS = $request->input('descripcionOS');
    $inventario->comentariosOS = $request->input('comentariosOS');
    $inventario->cantidad = $request->input('cantidad');
    $inventario->producto_id = $request->input('livesearchProduct');
    $inventario->OS_id = $var;
    $inventario->save();

    if($request->input('livesearchProduct2')){
    $inventario2 = new inventario;
    $inventario2->fecha = $request->input('fecha');
    $inventario2->numSerie = $request->input('numeroSerie2');
    $inventario2->descripcionOS = $request->input('descripcionOS2');
    $inventario2->comentariosOS = $request->input('comentariosOS2');
    $inventario2->cantidad = $request->input('cantidad2');
    $inventario2->producto_id = $request->input('livesearchProduct2');
    $inventario2->OS_id = $var;
    $inventario2->save();
    }

    if($request->input('livesearchProduct3')){
    $inventario3 = new inventario;
    $inventario3->fecha = $request->input('fecha');
    $inventario3->numSerie = $request->input('numeroSerie3');
    $inventario3->descripcionOS = $request->input('descripcionOS3');
    $inventario3->comentariosOS = $request->input('comentariosOS3');
    $inventario3->cantidad = $request->input('cantidad3');
    $inventario3->producto_id = $request->input('livesearchProduct3');
    $inventario3->OS_id = $var;
    $inventario3->save();
    }

    foreach ($request->estatusAdm as $est) {
          $estatus = new detAdm();
          $estatus->administrativo_id = $est;
          $estatus->OS_id = $var;
          $estatus->save();
    }

    $producto = catProd::findOrFail($request->livesearchProduct);
    $producto->cantidad = $producto->cantidad + 1;
    $producto->save();

    return redirect()->route('admin.orden.index')->with('success', 'Se creo con éxito la orden de servicio, revisa los detalles a continuación');

} *** JUSTO AQUI
```

estoy aplicando mal los if ? me podrian orientar ?

Aclaración, los tengo de esa forma ya que tengo una tabla en donde pueden seleccionar varios productos entonces ocupo hacer varios insert a las mismas tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Igual si agregas el mensaje de error será mas fácil poder identificar lo que esta mal en el código (**no es necesario responder este mensaje**)

Comment: Tu archivo de rutas?